# Square root of the derivation operator

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Let $E=\mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathbb C)$ and $D:E\to E$ the derivation operator.
> Is there a linear map $T:E\to E$ such that $T\circ T = D$?

I have an intuition that such an endomorphism cannot exist, but I don't see how to prove it.

**Note**: Fractional analysis gives results for some functions but we are far from the existence of a linear map over the whole space (as I understood it).

Comment: There is no unique notion of the square root of the derivative operator. Fractional calculus leads to several possible options that are not all unique. Moreover, fractional derivatives lose the locality properties of integer order derivatives so you might not even call half derivatives true square roots since their behaviors are so bizarre by comparison.

Comment: I should also mention.. The domains of definition for fractional derivatives are a bit difficult to get a handle on as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such $T$ exists, by simple linear algebra considerations.  Note that $\ker(D^n)$ is $n$-dimensional for each $n$ (consisting of the polynomials of degree $<n$).  In particular, $\ker(T^2)=\ker(D)$ is $1$-dimensional.  This means $T$ is not injective, so $\ker(T)$ must be nontrivial and thus $\ker(T)=\ker(T^2)$ since $\ker(T^2)$ is $1$-dimensional and contains $\ker(T)$.  In other words, if $Tx\in\ker(T)$, then $x\in \ker(T^2)=\ker(T)$ so $Tx=0$.  But now iterating this shows that if $T^nx\in\ker(T)$ then $Tx=0$ for any $n$, so $\ker(T^n)=\ker(T)$ is $1$-dimensional for all $n>0$.  This is a contradiction since $\ker(T^{2n})=\ker(D^n)$ is $n$-dimensional.